# Intellij create grails project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

when I create new project in IntelliJ on the left Grails is missing,I think there was some kiind of plugins/tools to install Grails on IntelliJ and then it will show up but where is it?

Comment: Please add versions of the Grails you wish to work with and Intellij Idea version.

Comment: The latest ones

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the grails in you project, you should check that the grails is included in your **build.gradle** file.
These are the main lines for basic building of the Grails framework.(There are other extensions you can add).

```
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"


grails {
    grailsVersion = '3.1.10'
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.grails:grails-core:$grailsVersion"
}
```

After adding those lines you should close the IntelliJ Idea and open it using the build.gradle file.

Then you should see the **grails-app [main]** directory.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij (I am using version 2016.2.5) does not support the Grails view (on the left side of screen) for Grails 3.x projects.  Hopefully in they will add this again for 3.x project I also miss that on the new projects.

EDITED: Intellij 2016.3.0 now says that Grails View is back for Grails 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Support for Grails exists in the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ IDEA. Since Grails is just a Gradle project, the Community version recognizes this, but you will not get code highlighting for things such a GSPs, intellisense and other features.

More information can on the differences can be found on their site: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html